# gfortran: how do i execute precompiled binaries?

Tags: linux, terminal, execution, gfortran, precompiled-binaries

I have a set of compiled gfortran binaries, these appear green (executable?) in my linux terminal and have no extension.

I would like to know how to execute these (a simple ./filename doesn't work).

Thank you.

Comment: What is the file type? Run the following `# file filename` and see if this is a real binary.

Comment: I get: 'simple_prime: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped'.

What is 'not stripped'? Could I be missing some libraries?